# react native state without class

Tags: react-native, slider, state

I'm new to react native and I'm trying to update the value of a slider in the UI when I slide it.
I've seen in this [example](http://nobrok.com/how-to-use-react-native-slider-to-take-input/) that they use the **state** but I don't have a class. I have a component.
This is my code:

```
export const PhaseModeDetailComponent = ({
  phase,
  editable,
  onChange,
  sliderValue
}: {
  phase: IPhase;
  editable: boolean;
  onChange?: (phase: IPhase) => void;
  sliderValue: number;
}) => {
    let leftIcon;
    let rightIcon;
    let minimumTrackTintColor;
    let maximumTrackTintColor;
    let minValue;
    let maxValue;
    let sliderStep;

    if (phase.oven_mode === 0) {
      leftIcon = open;
      rightIcon = closed;
      minimumTrackTintColor = Colors.bluish;
      maximumTrackTintColor = Colors.tomato;
      minValue = 0;
      maxValue = 100;
      sliderStep = 10;
    } else if (phase.oven_mode === 1) {
      leftIcon = convectionSmallCopy;
      rightIcon = steamSmallCopy;
      minimumTrackTintColor = Colors.white;
      maximumTrackTintColor = Colors.tomato;
      minValue = 10;
      maxValue = 90;
      sliderStep = 5;
    }

    return (
      <ImageBackground style={styles.container} source={combinedShape} resizeMode="stretch">
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Image style={styles.sliderIcons} source={leftIcon} resizeMode="contain" />
          <Slider
            style={{ height: '100%', flex: 1 }}
            minimumValue={minValue}
            maximumValue={maxValue}
            minimumTrackTintColor={minimumTrackTintColor}
            maximumTrackTintColor={maximumTrackTintColor}
            thumbTintColor="#fff"
            thumbImage={handle}
            disabled={!editable}
            step={sliderStep}
            value={phase.humidity_perc}
          />
          <Image style={styles.sliderIcons} source={rightIcon} resizeMode="contain" />
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <ScalableText
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              textAlign: 'right',
              paddingRight: 8,
              color: Colors.white,
              fontFamily: 'robotoRegular',
              fontSize: 22
            }}
          >
            {`${phase.humidity_perc}%`}
          </ScalableText>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
};
```

How can I update the value of the slider? In the example they use the state but I've read [here](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-without-constructor) that I cannot use it since I don't have a class.
Is there another way?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

React has a feature called `hooks` that is exactly what you are looking for. You can use state inside a function component.

Read more about it [in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

Here is an example taken straight from the docs:

```jsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I would recommend learning about the difference between Class Components and Function Components and starting with whichever one makes more sense to you.

Using a Class Component for the same example above would look something like this:

```jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Example extends Component {

  state = {
    count: 0
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>You clicked {this.state.count} times</p>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1})}>Click me</button>
      </div>     
    )
  }

}
```